# node.js mysql wildcard search unable to execute

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I just started using MySQL and nodejs for a school project and I'm unable to execute a wild search query without this error coming up:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near % at line 1

and below is a snippet of the code :

```
var movieName = request.body.movieName;
var sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie_name  = ?%";
db.query(sql,[movieName],function (error, result) {
    if(error){
        throw error;
    }
    else {
        respond.json(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't put in % unless your using a LIKE clause instead of = and even then you would have to put the % inside your parameter.  https://www.guru99.com/wildcards.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with: you seem to want `LIKE`, not an equality condition.

You can `concat()` the question mark in the query string:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie_name like concat(?, '%')";
```

Or better yet, you can concat it into the string variable:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie_name  like ?";
db.query(sql, [movieName + '%'],function (error, result) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LIKE` clause not equal sign `=`

Most simple method for this will be:

```
var movieName = request.body.movieName;
var sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie_name LIKE '%" + movieName "%'";
db.query(sql, function (error, result) {
    if(error){
        throw error;
    }
    else {
        respond.json(result);
    }
});
```